# WKWebView Unable to scroll after webView.reload() iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, wkwebview

I am creating 2 webViews. One for menu and one for content.

On the Menu (menuWebView) I reload every time to update the content in case the user is logged in.

If I reload the menuWebView, it reloads but now the scrollView is disabled.

tried reload() and reloadFromOrigin().

The size of the scrollview is the same with menuWebView ( the expected ).

This issue happens on iOS 10 devices and occasionally on iOS 12

Any idea?

Thank you.

```
if menuButtonPressed == false{
            hideMenuWebView(isHidden: menuButtonPressed)
            progressBar.isHidden = true
            setupRightBarButtonitemMenu(imageName: "menu_white", title: "Close",action:#selector(menuButtonTapped))
            menuButtonPressed = true
            menuWebView.reload()
}else{
}
```

Comment: is the menuWebView a child of the scrollView?

Comment: Not sure how to check that. I just have a default setup. Could you guide how to check that ?

Comment: did you create your scrollView through code or Storyboard?

Comment: I created the WKWebView from Code, and it comes with the scrollView by default.

Comment: I found out the problem is on the back-end and not mine. thanks a lot